# Uploading and sharing geotagged photos

Tags: photos, geotagging

I would like to be able to upload photos *with geotag data* to an online database that gives access to a controlled audience.

For example it is possible to use Picasa with a joint Gmail account that the photographer uploads to, but the viewer will have the login credential to the Gmail account and therefore can edit/delete these photos.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You could also do just what you said with Picasa, just make the album public or give them access with a link.

Comment: @jlehenbauer: I agree with Flow, the edited version seems good to me. I'm reopening this.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with Picasa. Simply create an upload account for the photographer, (you could then upload from your computer or directly from your phone) and choose to share the album or individual pictures with the viewer(s) via private link.